# How can I print strings based on ascending order of an index within a tuple

Tags: python, function, if-statement, tuples

I have 3 groups of student results: group_a, group_b and group_c

Each group contains a list of tuples which take this order: (student_number,score).

I would like to print a message for each student depending on their score:

- Each student within Group A : "Well done student {}. Your score was {}"
- Each student within Group B : "Good work student {}. Your score was {}"
- Each student within Group C : "Hi student {}. Your score was {}. You can do better than this."

In an attempt to achieve this, I combined all 3 groups before sorting them by the first element of the tuple.

```
  all_groups = group_a + group_b + group_c
  
  # take first element for sort

  def takeFirst(elem):
    return elem[0] 

 #using the 'takeFirst' function, sort tuple based on the first element
  all_groups.sort(key=takeFirst)

#each tuple reflects (student number, score)
  print(all_groups)
 [(1, 29), (2, 54), (3, 52), (4, 50), (5, 30), (6, 57), (7, 56), (8, 47), (9, 51), (10, 55)]
```

Next, I printed a message for each student depending on their score.

```
collection4 = []
collection5 = []
collection6 = []

for number, pair1 in enumerate(all_groups):
    # Unpack pair1: number, student_score
    student_number, score1 = pair1
    # print msg for each student. Attach every sentence into a 'collection' bucket.
    if score1 >=60:
        collection4.append('Well done student {}. Your score was {}.'.format(student_number, score1))
    elif score1 >=50 and score1<=59:
        collection5.append('Good work student {}. Your score was {}.'.format(student_number, score1))
    else:
        collection6.append('Hi student {}. Your score was {}. You can do better than this.'.format(student_number, score1))
```

Next, I combined collection 4, 5 and 6 into one bucket.

```
totalcollection = collection4 + collection5 + collection6
```

However, when I print the content of the 'totalcollection' variable, the results are not ordered in ascending order of the student number.

May I know how I can solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs here:

```
totalcollection = collection4 + collection5 + collection6
```

totalcollection will first add collection4, then 5 and 6, however suppose if student with id 1 doesn't find its way in collection 4 and ends up in collection 6 then it will be added in totalcollection after all the results in collection 4 and 5 have already been added which will disrupt the order.

A simple solution is to just use a single collection and append everything in it so that the results are ordered.

```
totalcollection = []


for number, pair1 in enumerate(all_groups):
    # Unpack pair1: number, student_score
    student_number, score1 = pair1
    # print msg for each student. Attach every sentence into a 'collection' bucket.
    if score1 >= 60:
        totalcollection .append(
            'Well done student {}. Your score was {}.'.format(student_number, score1))
    elif score1 >= 50 and score1 <= 59:
        totalcollection .append(
            'Good work student {}. Your score was {}.'.format(student_number, score1))
    else:
        totalcollection .append('Hi student {}. Your score was {}. You can do better than this.'.format(
            student_number, score1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You sorted everything based on **student number**. Then you created subgroups
based on **test score**. At that point, each sub-group was sorted by student
number. Then you just glued the test-score-based subgroups together. There is
no reason to expect the resulting group to be sorted by student number -- the
subgroups were created according to a different attribute.

You can simplify things by using more meaningful data. Rather than raw tuples,
consider more declarative options like `namedtuple`, `dataclass`, or `attrs`
class. For example:

```
from collections import namedtuple

# The raw data.
raw_data = [(1, 29), (3, 52), (2, 40), (4, 50), (7, 70), (5, 65), (6, 17)]

# Create meaningful objects holding that information.
TestResult = namedtuple('TestResult', 'student_number score')
test_results = [TestResult(*tup) for tup in raw_data]

# Tuples automatically sort by checking their first elements first.
test_results.sort()
```

And if you want to generate messages, just write a function taking
a `TestResult` and returning the message. Don't co-mingle that
logic with other concerns like iterating over all of the test results.

```
def result_message(tr):
    fmt = (
        'Well done student {}. Your score was {}.' if tr.score >= 60 else
        'Good work student {}. Your score was {}.' if 50 <= tr.score <= 59 else
        'Hi student {}. Your score was {}. You can do better than this.'
    )
    return fmt.format(tr.student_number, tr.score)
```

When you want to print, it's easy and you'll still have the order you wanted:

```
for tr in test_results:
    print(result_message(tr))
```

Comment: Thank you @FMc. Good to know another way of solving the problem.